# How can I debug that browser is not loading translation file, when running the instance of selenium chrome driver. Framework : webdriver:io

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

> Framework: Webdriver.io.
> Language: Typescript
> chrome: 113

```
import { addRunner } from './src/config/runner';
import { addReportPortal } from './src/config/reportPortal';
import type { Options } from '@wdio/types';
import { getBaseUrl, getEnv, getTagConfig, printEnvs } from './src/config/env';
import { hooks } from './src/config/hooks';

printEnvs();

const debug = getEnv('DEBUG');
const defaultTimeoutInterval = 60000;

const baseConfig: Options.Testrunner = {
  //
  // ====================
  // Runner Configuration
  // ====================
  // WebdriverIO supports running e2e tests as well as unit and component tests.
  runner: 'local',
  autoCompileOpts: {
    autoCompile: true,
    tsNodeOpts: {
      project: './tsconfig.json',
      transpileOnly: true,
    },
  },

  //
  // ==================
  // Specify Test Files
  // ==================
  // Define which test specs should run. The pattern is relative to the directory
  // of the configuration file being run.
  //
  // The specs are defined as an array of spec files (optionally using wildcards
  // that will be expanded). The test for each spec file will be run in a separate
  // worker process. In order to have a group of spec files run in the same worker
  // process simply enclose them in an array within the specs array.
  //
  // If you are calling `wdio` from an NPM script (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script),
  // then the current working directory is where your `package.json` resides, so `wdio`
  // will be called from there.
  //
  specs: getTagConfig().specs,
  // Patterns to exclude.
  exclude: [
    // 'path/to/excluded/files'
  ],
  //
  // ============
  // Capabilities
  // ============
  // Define your capabilities here. WebdriverIO can run multiple capabilities at the same
  // time. Depending on the number of capabilities, WebdriverIO launches several test
  // sessions. Within your capabilities you can overwrite the spec and exclude options in
  // order to group specific specs to a specific capability.
  //
  // First, you can define how many instances should be started at the same time. Let's
  // say you have 3 different capabilities (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) and you have
  // set maxInstances to 1; wdio will spawn 3 processes. Therefore, if you have 10 spec
  // files and you set maxInstances to 10, all spec files will get tested at the same time
  // and 30 processes will get spawned. The property handles how many capabilities
  // from the same test should run tests.
  //
  maxInstances: debug ? 1 : 10,
  //
  // If you have trouble getting all important capabilities together, check out the
  // Sauce Labs platform configurator - a great tool to configure your capabilities:
  // https://saucelabs.com/platform/platform-configurator
  //
  capabilities: [
    {
      // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
      // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
      // 5 instances get started at a time.
      maxInstances: 5,
      //
      browserName: 'chrome',
      'goog:chromeOptions': {
        excludeSwitches: ['enable-automation'],
        args: ['--accept-lang=en', '--lang=en', '--override-language-detection'],
      },

      acceptInsecureCerts: true,
      // If outputDir is provided WebdriverIO can capture driver session logs
      // it is possible to configure which logTypes to include/exclude.
      // excludeDriverLogs: ['*'], // pass '*' to exclude all driver session logs
      // excludeDriverLogs: ['bugreport', 'server'],
    },
  ],
  //
  // ===================
  // Test Configurations
  // ===================
  // Define all options that are relevant for the WebdriverIO instance here
  //
  // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
  logLevel: 'warn',
  //
  // Set specific log levels per logger
  // loggers:
  // - webdriver, webdriverio
  // - @wdio/browserstack-service, @wdio/devtools-service, @wdio/sauce-service
  // - @wdio/mocha-framework, @wdio/jasmine-framework
  // - @wdio/local-runner
  // - @wdio/sumologic-reporter
  // - @wdio/cli, @wdio/config, @wdio/utils
  // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
  // logLevels: {
  //     webdriver: 'info',
  //     '@wdio/appium-service': 'info'
  // },
  //
  // If you only want to run your tests until a specific amount of tests have failed use
  // bail (default is 0 - don't bail, run all tests).
  bail: 0,
  //
  // Set a base URL in order to shorten url command calls. If your `url` parameter starts
  // with `/`, the base url gets prepended, not including the path portion of your baseUrl.
  // If your `url` parameter starts without a scheme or `/` (like `some/path`), the base url
  // gets prepended directly.
  baseUrl: getBaseUrl(),
  //
  // Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.
  waitforTimeout: 10000,
  //
  // Default timeout in milliseconds for request
  // if browser driver or grid doesn't send response
  connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
  //
  // Default request retries count
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  //
  // Test runner services
  // Services take over a specific job you don't want to take care of. They enhance
  // your test setup with almost no effort. Unlike plugins, they don't add new
  // commands. Instead, they hook themselves up into the test process.
  services: [],

  // Framework you want to run your specs with.
  // The following are supported: Mocha, Jasmine, and Cucumber
  // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/frameworks
  //
  // Make sure you have the wdio adapter package for the specific framework installed
  // before running any tests.
  framework: 'cucumber',
  //
  // The number of times to retry the entire specfile when it fails as a whole
  // specFileRetries: 1,
  //
  // Delay in seconds between the spec file retry attempts
  // specFileRetriesDelay: 0,
  //
  // Whether or not retried specfiles should be retried immediately or deferred to the end of the queue
  // specFileRetriesDeferred: false,
  //
  // Test reporter for stdout.
  // The only one supported by default is 'dot'
  // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/dot-reporter
  reporters: ['spec'],

  //
  // If you are using Cucumber you need to specify the location of your step definitions.
  cucumberOpts: {
    // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features
    require: ['src/steps/**/*.steps.ts'],
    // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors
    backtrace: false,
    // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
    requireModule: [],
    // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
    dryRun: false,
    // <boolean> abort the run on first failure
    failFast: false,
    // <boolean> hide step definition snippets for pending steps
    snippets: true,
    // <boolean> hide source uris
    source: true,
    // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
    strict: false,
    // <string> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
    tagExpression: getEnv('TEST_SUITE_TAG'),
    // <number> timeout for step definitions
    timeout: debug ? 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 : defaultTimeoutInterval,
    // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.
    ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false,
  },
  execArgv: debug ? ['--inspect'] : [],
};

addRunner(baseConfig);
addReportPortal(baseConfig);

export const config: Options.Testrunner = {
  ...baseConfig,
  ...hooks,
};
```

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
    "@types/node": "^18.16.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.2",
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.8.8",
    "@wdio/types": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.39.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "mailosaur": "^8.6.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "e2e": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.ts --inspect",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.ts --fix",
    "lint-ci": "eslint . --ext .js,.ts --quiet",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "test-ci": "jest --ci --coverage --runInBand --detectOpenHandles"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^8.8.7",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.8.8",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.8.7",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "chromedriver": "^113.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.1.1",
    "wdio-reportportal-reporter": "^7.6.0",
    "wdio-reportportal-service": "^7.3.1",
    "winston": "^3.8.2"
  }
}
```

1. I am trying to set the language but it does not work
2. The application is also not loading the translation json file when running the automated version, but when working manually it does have all the json file under -> F12 -> application -> local storage

How to make the test suite work?